# LINQ Select certain cell in DataGridView depending on other cell in row

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I am brand spanking new to LINQ and am trying to use it in my current hobby project. I have a `datagridview` where the first cell of each row is a `datagridviewcheckbox`, and the 4th cell is a string.

If the checkbox is checked, I need to add the 4th cell's value to a list.

At first I tried:

```
var selectedID = from c in multiContactLookup.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>() 
                              select multiContactLookup.Rows[c.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value;
```

That didn't work because the checked cells are programatically unselected so `c` is never a value.

Then I tried:

```
var sel2 = from r in multiContactLookup.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                       where r.Cells[0].Value is true select r.Cells[4].Value;
```

but somehow my syntax is wrong.

Using LINQ, how can I select the rows where the first cell is checked then select the value of the first cell?  Do I have to split this into two collections?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
IEnumerable<string> values = multiContactLookup.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => (bool)row.Cells[0].Value)
    .Select(row => (string)row.Cells[3].Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the answer you have been looking for, but...

`DataGridView` (as most win-forms controls) is not the best source to start with LINQ. Most collections do not implement the correct `IEnumerable<T>` interface. That's the reason why you need the `Cast()` workaround.

In general, try to move your applications behavior away from controls and into the data. Maybe your grid is connected to a `DataTable`. In this case register the `DataTable`'s events for changed data and work with the values of the `DataRow`, instead of the `DataGridViewRow` and its cells.